# DRF Viewset custom "create" method does not call serializer custom "create" method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

referring to the code below. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to create a new instance of "Survey" when an "Answer" is created.
The POST request sent is: `{"choice":123}`

First problem:     "survey": [
        "This field is required."
    ]. Removing "survey" from the serializer fields gets around this but I'm not sure this is correct. Note that both "Survey" & "Choice" have one-to-many relationship with "Answer" via foreign key.

Second problem: The custom create method in the serializer is not called because the test print "HELLO" I put in is not executed and nothing is created.

Been stuck on this for a while, any ideas guys? Much appreciate it.

```
class AddAnswerView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data.get(
            "items") if 'items' in request.data else request.data
        many = isinstance(data, list)
        serializer = AnswerSerializer(data=data, many=many)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Survey
        fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return models.Survey.objects.create(**validated_data)


class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Answer
        fields = ('choice', 'survey')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('HELLO')
        user = self.context['request'].user
        new_survey = models.Survey.objects.create(user=user)
        answer = models.Answer.objects.create(survey=new_survey, 
          **validated_data)
        return answer
```

Comment: have you check you serializer is validated or not

Answer (score 1):

You should use `viewsets.ModelViewSet` instead of `viewsets.ViewSet`

Then declare `serializer_class = AnswerSerializer` to make `create` method work.

`This field is required` is error from Django Model not djangorestframework.
You must do some tricks in `create` method to passing it.